# Build not showing up on itunes connect

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store-connect, xcode10

I uploaded one app on app store. Then I uploaded new app with the same distribution certificates and provision profiles. Package name is also same for this new app. my previous version was 1.5 and I uploaded a new version 1.6 with new app and it was successfully uploaded on store but it does not show up on itunes activity.

[image]

I am using react native technology for app and xcode version 10.1

Comment: Did you already create the new version 1.6 on App Store Connect?

Comment: I added some permissions which are now mandatory for uploading app in info.plist and I was able to see new version in Activity panel of itunes connect.

Comment: It mostly happens if you don't add key's to info.plist(Something like CameraUsagedescrption)while using the fuctionality.Also check your mail as Apple sends the mail for the reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you have some issues in your build.
Please check your emails, I suppose you have all the issues related in your email address.
It might be something related to push notification certificates maybe or something else.

Thank you